# Logic in PHP, why is this happening?

Tags: php

```
function x() {return -1;}
echo x();
echo "<br>";
if(x()) {echo "True";} else {echo "False";}
```

output:

```
-1
True
```

Why am I getting 'True' outputted, surely the `if()` test would fail as it's negative?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you can only test on true or false.

False is defined as `0`, while true is defined as `not 0`. So `-1` is just as much `true` as 1, 2, 3 etc.

To make sure you're getting the right result, make a real comparison.

Comment: how can I test for only positive results then?

Comment: @Chud37 `if(x() > 0)` should help you with that.

Comment: `if (x() >= 0)` if you also want to check for 0 inclusive.

Comment: Well another function I have either returns a negative number or a string.  So I could just do is_string surely?

Comment: You shouldn't really be returning different types in a single function. It's okay if you return FALSE or an int/string but you should never be returning an Int OR string.

Comment: @Chud37 Yes, since `is_string` returns a boolean, you can use the return value as a condition.

Comment: @MatthewMcGovern The way I understood it, it returns a string on success and '-1' on failure...which would be the same as `false` in this context.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium Ah fair enough, that's fine. I prefer type defined functions, rather than typeless.

Answer (score 5):

`-1` is considered `TRUE` in boolean context. See [Converting to boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) in the PHP manual.

Answer (score 4):

Only numeric 0 values are false in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Answer (score 0):

0 is false and everything else is true. That's why !

Answer (score 0):

In PHP a `-1` is true as it isn't `0`. Use a real comparison like:

```
if(x() <= 0) { ...do stuff... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

`var_dump(x()); //output: int(-1)`

and casted to boolean:

`var_dump((bool)x()); //output: bool(true)`

`-1` is not `false` in PHP. You could check if it's `> 0`?

Answer (score 0):

All what is 0 is false and everything else is true. [Wikipedia article about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_and_false)

Answer (score 0):

Converting to boolean in PHP

To explicitly convert a value to boolean, use the (bool) or (boolean) casts. However, in most cases the cast is unnecessary, since a value will be automatically converted if an operator, function or control structure requires a boolean argument.

See also Type Juggling.

When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:

the boolean FALSE itself
the integer 0 (zero)
the float 0.0 (zero)
the empty string, and the string "0"
an array with zero elements
an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
the special type NULL (including unset variables)
SimpleXML objects created from empty tags
Every other value is considered TRUE (including any resource).

Warning
-1 is considered TRUE, like any other non-zero (whether negative or positive) number!

Source http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting